# error in file uploading using yii 2.0.3

Tags: yii2

Everything is fine before I submitting the form. When I submitted the form It gives error at a particular line in the function for the form in the controller. The line is as:

```
$model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
```

View file(signup.php) is as:

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
/* @var $model \frontend\models\SignupForm */

$this->title = 'Signup';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-signup">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>Please fill out the following fields to signup:</p>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-signup','options'=> ['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'firstname') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'lastname') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'email') ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'photo')->fileInput() ?>
                <?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton('Signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                </div>
            <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I having write here only the function for that particular form. Controller file (SiteController.php) is as under:

```
namespace frontend\controllers;

use Yii;
use common\models\LoginForm;
use frontend\models\PasswordResetRequestForm;
use frontend\models\ResetPasswordForm;
use frontend\models\SignupForm;
use frontend\models\ContactForm;
use yii\base\InvalidParamException;
use yii\web\BadRequestHttpException;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $photo = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'photo');
            $model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension); **// error is in this line.**
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('signup', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Model file (SignupForm.php) is as:

```
namespace frontend\models;

use common\models\User;
use yii\base\Model;
use Yii;

/**
 * Signup form
 */
class SignupForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $photo;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['username', 'required'],
            ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
            ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

            ['firstname','required'],
            ['firstname','string','min' => 2, 'max' => 20],

            ['lastname','required'],
            ['lastname','string','min' => 2, 'max' => 20],

            [['photo'],'file'],

            ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
            ['email', 'required'],
            ['email', 'email'],
            ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

            ['password', 'required'],
            ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Signs user up.
     *
     * @return User|null the saved model or null if saving fails
     */
    public function signup()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            $user = new User();
            $user->firstname = $this->firstname;
            $user->lastname = $this->lastname;
            $user->photo = $this->photo;
            $user->username = $this->username;
            $user->email = $this->email;
            $user->setPassword($this->password);
            $user->generateAuthKey();
            if ($user->save()) {
                return $user;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

May anybody tell me what is the exact problem and give me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show the error message..

Comment: Thanks for the replies.
Now the error message is this as I have done a change said by Toxa as he is right:
 PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object at :
in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php
line of code where error comes is:

'$model->photo->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension);'

Answer (score 2):

Your propirties `$model->file` is null. In Yii2, unlike Yii 1.*, you need set `UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'photo')` to `$model->file`, and than save file.

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'photo');
$model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->extension);
```

Also you have't property `file`, in your model (SignupForm.php), you have `photo`, you need change code to:

```
$model->photo= UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'photo');
$model->photo->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->photo->baseName.'.'.$model->photo->extension);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are right but my problem isn't solved I am still getting error. The error is as :

PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object at : in C:\xampp\htdocs\advanced\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php.

 line of code where error comes is: 

`$model->photo->saveAs('uploads/'.$model->file->baseName.'.'.$model->file->exten‌​sion);`

Comment: It is meaning $model->file is "null". You need check $_FILE array, also should save file after validate form

Comment: Hi Toxa, Thanks for the reply. In controller's actionSignup() function I have make a change by validating the model as:
`if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate())`
and rules for _photo_ in _model_ file as:
`[['photo'],'file'],
            ['photo','required'],
            ['photo','string'],`
Now when I submit the form after filling every thing it says:
**Photo cannot be blank.** but the _photo_ field is not left empty by me. Why he is the giving the validation error.

Comment: Problem with `load()` function, after `$model->photo= UploadedFile::getInstances($model,'photo');` in the `$model->photo` you have object after `$model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())` you have a empty string, because `load()` takes data from `$_POST` and in it also is `photo` field . Then you try validate data, but you can't.

Comment: Hi toxa, Thanks for the reply. Some for info. Now I have removed `$model->validate()` so now error for:-
 **$_POST** is like:
**$_POST = [
    '_csrf' => 'b0lWVUIxVjIKBzQlDXkZSFx8GwYKfCRaLCIeFHNjElgOBg8ZbwI/XA==',
    'SignupForm' => [
        'firstname' => 'test',
        'lastname' => 'one',
        'username' => 'testone',
        'email' => 'testone@example.com',
        'photo' => '',
        'password' => '123456',
    ],
    'signup-button' => '',
];**
_comment too long so posting in next comment._

Comment: and for **$_FILES** is like:
**$_FILES = [
    'SignupForm' => [
        'name' => [
            'photo' => '11138548_10152668544056537_1131951508697276037_n.jpg',
        ],
        'type' => [
            'photo' => 'image/jpeg',
        ],
        'tmp_name' => [
            'photo' => 'C:\\xampp\\tmp\\php2389.tmp',
        ],
        'error' => [
            'photo' => 0,
        ],
        'size' => [
            'photo' => 66125,
        ],
    ],
];**

Answer (score 0):

I did it something like this and its working.
In **UploadForm.php** model :

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;
use Yii;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
    public $file;

    public $name;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['file'], 'file','skipOnEmpty' => false,'extensions' => 'jpg, png', 'mimeTypes' => 'image/jpeg, image/png'],
        ];
    }
}
```

In controller

```
use app\models\UploadForm;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

public function actionProfileImage()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $fileName = $this->userData->username . '.jpg';
            $image = $model->file->saveAs(Yii::$app->basePath.'/files/profile/' . $fileName);
            if($image){
                \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('msg', 'Profile Image Updated Successfully.');
                return $this->redirect('profile-image', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->render('profileImage');
}
```

In view file :

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'form-profile','options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(); ?>
<?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('keywords', 'Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'submit-button']) ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```